# Passing a variable into a function as a character

Tags: r, function, posixct

I'm having difficulty passing a `POSIXct` variable into a function correctly. I'm using the Quandl package, but I don't think it's particular to my problem.

```
library(Quandl)

quandl_get <-
  function(sym, start_date = "2017-01-01") {
require(devtools)
require(Quandl)
# create a vector with all lines
tryCatch(Quandl(c(
  paste0("WIKI/", sym, ".8"),  #  Adj. Open
  paste0("WIKI/", sym, ".9"),  # Adj. High
  paste0("WIKI/", sym, ".10"), # Adj. Low
  paste0("WIKI/", sym, ".11"), # Adj. Close
  paste0("WIKI/", sym, ".12")), # Adj. Volume
  start_date = start_date,
  type = "zoo"
))
}
```

This function works fine provided it uses the default start date.

However, If I try to pass a POSIXct variable into it, I generate a data frame with zero observations, indicating that it Quandl does not like that parameter.

```
maxdate <- Sys.time() #POSIXct object - "2018-07-15 14:03:05 EST"
nextdate <- maxdate + 86400 #"2018-07-16 14:03:05 EST"

df <- quandl_get(sym = i, start_date = nextdate)
```

If I try to pass a POSIXct variable into function, it still does not work.

```
maxdate <- Sys.time() #POSIXct object - "2018-07-15 14:03:05 EST"
nextdate <- maxdate + 86400 #"2018-07-16 14:03:05 EST"

df <- quandl_get(sym = i, start_date = as.character(nextdate))
```

This seems like it should be a simple solution, but evades me.

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: Try converting it to a yyyy-mm-dd character string before passing it to Quandl.